# How can I View Who a Comment was From on Facebook API

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to export all the comments on a post with Facebook Graph.

I can get all the comments fine along with the tags but I'm having some problems getting the user who actually commented.  I own the page and post that I'm doing this too. Is there a specific permission I need? I have manage_pages, pages_show_list, and public_profiles.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is important that you are using a **Page Token**. With a simpel App Token, you will not get the `from` field in the response.